# List json parsing

Tags: logstash

I have a probleme to create a list of json object. this is my config:

```
input {

file {#settings...}
}

filter {

mutate {

add_field => {"book_title" => "%{Book_title}"}

add_field => {"book_price" => "%{Book_price}"}

       }

mutate {

rename => { "book_title" => "[book_market][book_title]"

            "book_price" => "[book_market][book_price]" }

        }
}
```

I want book_market be list for some reason even it has one object

```
ruby {

code => "

event['book_market'] = [event['book_market']]

"

}

}
```

the result here after execution:

```
"book_market" : [ {

"book_title":"title",

"book_price":"price"

}]
```

it's that I want !
But in a second time a new book arrives from another file... the probleme here with the same config I lost the first json object because book_market is overwritten.. I want to insert the new object in book_market list.

Thank you for help !

Comment: I don't exactly understand. How does your second event overwrite the first? They are separate events and are handled separately. E.g. how do you merge both events into 1?

Comment: in the second event I want to add a second json object containing a new book information and add it to book_market list. The mutate and rename option override the first book, it creates a new book_market list with one book (the new book).. I want to insert the new information to elasticsearch document (in book_market list).

Comment: The second event has no notion of the first event unless you have some custom logic in it that keep track of it. From your config, you don't. So the reason your second event 'overwrites' the first event is that the first event is gone and done with. There is nothing to overwrite.

Comment: yes..in both events I save the result in a document to elasticsearch..I want the second event insert new information in book_market list.

Comment: This is not a filter problem then. You need to look into updates on the ES side (output filter). By default ES will always do an insert. If you specify the same documentId it will likely (not sure) do an overwrite. You need to configure your output so it can find the previous documentId and then script the update (because ES does not update anything, any update in ES is a delete + reindex operation so this will also be costly). You may be better off looking to a filter solution, for example the aggregate-filter-plugin to track your events.